# How to input a range of values for a constraint in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am trying to write in a constraint in R for a linear programming problem

Eg. the value of X is greater 6 but not greater than 10

```r
6 <= X <= 10
```

I tried `x <- 6:10`, print x but it does not meet the integer signs. (greater than, but not greater than)

Comment: `x >= 6 & x <= 10`

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! `6:10` just returns the vector 6,7,8,9,10. If you want to write a constraint, you probably want something like `if(x>=6 & x<=10)`, meaning x greater or equal 6 AND x smaller of equal 10.

Comment: Depends on the solver/ modeling tool.